# NodeJS Insert several row

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have 2 questions at the moment. First one, I would like to know how to insert other data in ma table in one request,

```
app.post('/api/domain/:id/translation.json', function (req, res) {
var domain_id = req.params.id;

 ADD this// Insert INTO translation_to_lang ('lang_id' which mean  result.insertID, 'value') VALUES ("' + req.body.lang_id + '", "' + req.body.value + '");

connection.query("INSERT INTO translation (`key`, `domain_id`) VALUES ('" + req.body.key + "', '" + domain_id +"');", function(error, result) {
 if (error) throw(error);
 var domain_id = result[0];

 if (domain_id !== undefined) {
   setTimeout(function () {
     res.status(400);
     res.send({
         code: 400,
         message: 'Bad Request'
     });
   }, 1000);
 }
 console.log(result);

 connection.query('SELECT * FROM translation WHERE id = "' + result.insertId + '"', function(error, data_insert) {
   setTimeout(function () {
     res.send({
         code: 201,
         message: 'success',
         datas: data_insert
     });
   }, 1000);
 });
});
});
```

And I have an error when I try to post data from domain_id which doesn't exists, if try out make condition, for example ***'/api/domain/44/translation.json'***, there is no 44 id inside my bdd at domain row I just would like than my api res send status 400 bad request but my condition doesn't work and I have this error message:

> ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`restapi`.`translation`, CONSTRAINT `translation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `domain` (`id`))

It just from post than there is the problem but if you want see all say me.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't form queries like you're doing, e.g. concatenating strings, this is prone to SQL injection attacks you should use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert statement fails because that foreign key must exists on related table, which throws error.

So your check for result[0] is irrelevant. You need to check your error itself. And as mentioned in comments, you may consider **mysql.format** for **SQL Injection** too such as

```
var query = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM translation WHERE id = ?;", tId);
```

try your code such as

```
app.post('/api/domain/:id/translation.json', function(req, res) {
var insertQuery = mysql.format("INSERT INTO translation (`key`, `domain_id`) VALUES (?,?);", [req.body.key, domain_id]);
connection.query(insertQuery, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        // check for constraint error

        return res.status(400).send({
            code: 400,
            message: 'Bad Request'
        });
    }

    console.log(result);
    var selectQuery = mysql.format("SELECT * FROM translation WHERE id = ?;", result[0].insertId);
    connection.query(selectQuery, function(error, data_insert) {

        return res.send({
            code: 201,
            message: 'success',
            datas: data_insert
        });

    });
});});
```

Comment: but now i got this error. **TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined**                                                                                                              EDIT : Solved. Thanks that was exactly what i want.